# spock and clover integration

Tags: maven, spock, clover

In my project, we are using spock for unit testing. I want to configure spock test cases with clover so that it can generate the coverage report. I have followed steps and configure it in maven. However, I am not able to configure it properly.
Could anyone guide me, to configure clover with spock?

my groovy test cases are in src/test/groovy package.

Thanks,
Jay Patel

Comment: StackOverflow works like this: You provide sample code + configuration + maybe error messages, ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then you explain what does not work and how you expect it to work instead. Others can use the MCVE in order to reproduce the problem and spot possible errors. This way they can present a solution. SO does not work like: "I describe my problem in two abstract plain prose sentences and let others do the whole job for me." You would be very lucky to get meaningful answers that way.

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone guide me, to configure Clover with Spock?

What problem exactly do you have? I'm asking, because tests written in Spock are no different from tests written in any other framework. As long as you build these classes with Clover and execute tests, you shall be able to get code coverage reports.

Please also note that Clover introduced a dedicated support for Spock's test iterations in version 3.3.0. So make sure you're using the latest version of Clover. I suggest Atlassian Clover 4.1.2 (the last version released by Atlassian) or OpenClover 4.2.0 (released by community).